# Cant get the value from database with inner join using yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I cant get the value selected from database using yii framework with inner join.My controller is sitecontroller.php and view file is adavance_search_result.php.I got the error "

Property "Job.location" is not defined.

C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php(145) "

Job table fields

```
id             int (100)            
user_id        int(100)         
posted_by      varchar(100) 
title          varchar(100) 
key_skills     varchar(200) 
no_vacancy     int(11)          
category_id    int(11)              
experience     int(11)          
contact_email  varchar(100)         
company_name   varchar(100)         
salary         double               
location_id    int int(100)
```

location
   1.id
   2.title

My controller code is

```
  public function actionadvance_search_result() {
     $title = $_GET['title'];
     $experience = $_GET['experience'];
     $location = $_GET['location'];
     $category = $_GET['category'];
     $salary_min = $_GET['salary_min'];
     $salary_max = $_GET['salary_max'];

     $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
     $criteria->select = 't.title,  location.title,  t.key_skills, t.description, t.no_vacancy, t.experience, t.company_name, t.salary';
     $criteria->join = 'INNER JOIN location ON t.location_id = location.id';
     if($experience != "") {
        $criteria->addCondition("(title like '%$title%' or  key_skills like '%$title%') and (experience like '%$experience%')");
     }
     if($location != "") {
        $criteria->addCondition("location_id like '%$location%'");
     }

     if($category != "") {
        $criteria->addCondition("category_id like '%$category%'");
     }
     if($salary_min != "" && $salary_max != "") {
        $criteria->addCondition("salary >= '$salary_min' and salary <= '$salary_max'");
     }

     $count = Job::model()->count($criteria);
     $pages = new CPagination($count);
     $pages->pageSize = 2;
     $pages->applyLimit($criteria);
     $model = Job::model()->findAll($criteria);

     $number_rec = count($model);
     if($number_rec <= 0) {
        $this->render('search_result1', array('model' => $model));
     }
     else {
        $this->render('advance_search_result', array(
                                                    'model' => $model,
                                                    'pages' => $pages
                                               ));
     }
  }
```

My view page is

```
  <div>
     <div>
        <h1>Search Results</h1>
        <ul style="list-style:none; ">
           <?php
           foreach($model as $models) {
              $job_id = $models->id;
              ?>
              <li>
                 <p><?php echo CHtml::link($models->title); ?></p>
                 <p><?php echo CHtml::link($models->location->title); ?></p>
                 <p><?php echo $models->company_name; ?></p>
                 <p><?php echo $models->description; ?></p>
                 <p>Keyskill:<?php echo $models->key_skills; ?><p>
              </li>
              </br>
           <?php
           }
           ?>
        </ul>
        <p><?php $this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
                                                  'pages' => $pages,
                                             )) ?></p>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Model is job.php

Code

```
<?php

  class Job extends CActiveRecord
{
 public $title;
 public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
 {

return parent::model($className);
 }
public function tableName()
{
    return 'jobs';
}

public function rules()
{

return array(
          array('title,key_skills,description,no_vacancy,
category_id,experience,contact_email,company_name,company_name,salary,location_id','required'),
    );
}
public function relations()
  {
 return array(
'location' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'location', 'id'),
 );
  }
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'user_id' => 'User_ID',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'key_skills' => 'Key_skills',
    );
}
public function search()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('title',$this->title);
    $criteria->compare('key_skills',$this->key_skills,true);
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
}
```

?>

Model-location.php

```
 <?php
 class Location extends CActiveRecord
 {
  public $title;
 public $Ltitle;
 public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
  {
 return parent::model($className);
  }
public function tableName()
{
    return 'location';
}

 public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('title,description','required'),
    );
}
public function relations(){
   return array(
'job' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Job', 'id'),
);    
}

}
?>
```

Anybody help me?

Comment: What columns Job table has?

Comment: I had added job table fields,updated above code,plz check it.

Comment: Plz check the updated code,i have two tables jobs and location,both table have the fields name 'title'.So i used alis name.

Comment: You're got an addCondition using `(title like '%$title%'` -- shouldn't that be `(ltitle like '%$title%'`?

Comment: Used tilte in query for 'title' field in  job table,Location is search with 'location_id' in job table.I want 'title' in job table and 'title' in location table.

Answer (score 0):

add and see if it works then

```
$criteria->with = array(
    'location'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do Job and Location table have relation  ?
 If yes then why should you not use the relation in yii. It is very easy to use as compare to you did. So my advice is if table have relation like primary key and foreign key then create model using Gii Module in yii.

and after that you only do

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = array('t.title,location.title as ltitle');
$criteria->with = array('location');
if($location != "") {
 $criteria->compare('t.theField_name' , $someThing);
}
$getValues = Job::model()->findAll($criteria);

foreach($getValues as $val){
    echo $val->location->title;//title from location table.
    echo $val->title;//title from job table.
}
```

You also add a few things in your job,location model below are the details.

First you add below code into your job model file

```
//Job Model.
public function relations()
{
//NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
// class name for the relations automatically generated below.
return array(
    'location' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Location', 'id'),
);
}
```

And then add below code into your location model file

```
public function relations(){
  // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
  // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
  return array(
 'job' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Job', 'id'),
  );    
}
```

and also make sure that id field in location table that have set primary key and In job table location_id is as a foreign key.

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: location_id in job table is id of location table

Comment: you also try with $val->location->title to get title from location table. And from job table to get title you should write $val->title.

Comment: Now my error is 'Property "Job.location" is not defined'

Comment: can you please post your whole code so I can see it and then help to solve it ?

Comment: You have to replace below code with my code                         $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = 't.title,  location.title,  t.key_skills, t.description, t.no_vacancy, t.experience, t.company_name, t.salary';
     $criteria->join = 'INNER JOIN location ON t.location_id = location.id';.

Comment: i had  replaced my code with your code,but no change.

Comment: Now error is Trying to get property of non-object

C:\wamp\www\jobsite_orginal\protected\modules\jobseeker\views\site\advance_search_result.php(11)".Line 11 is  <?php echo CHtml::link($models->location->title ); ?>

Comment: Ok now print your query results means echo "<pre>";print_r($model); echo "</pre>"; in your controller file and put exit before "$number_rec = count($model);". What the output will you get ? please post here.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Job Object ( [title] => Cochi [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [key_skills] => html, css [description] => php,jquery [no_vacancy] => 3 [experience] => 2 [company_name] => Impulse [salary] => 2 ) [_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array ( ) [_c:CActiveRecord:private] => [_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => [_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t [_errors:CModel:private] => Array ( ) [_validators:CModel:private] => [_scenario:CModel:private] => update [_e:CComponent:private] => [_m:CComponent:private] => ) )